# Can't compile for arch=arm64 on OSX Yosemite terminal

Tags: c++, ios, iphone, xcode

In terminal prompt on OSX Yosemite I am running a command line
build on some 3rd party code using xcode command line tools, I don't seem
to be able to specify arch=arm64 as a flag which is recognised by the compiler

When I type c++ -v I get this

gcc version 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3) (MacPorts apple-gcc42 5666.3_13)

When I type cc -v

Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.54) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0
Thread model: posix

So this seems to be the problem c++ is symlinked to gcc, how do I set to clang

I have Xcode6 command line tools installed but also have a parallel copy of Xcode 5 installed
so I think somewhere things have got mixed up. I need to keep both versions

Thanks

Comment: You need clang 3.4 or 3.5, which is in x-code 5+.

Comment: Hi I have Xcode 6 installed so why are tools not using clang. How do I change command line tools to use clang

Comment: OK got a bit further c++ is sym linked to gcc on my mac, cc seems to be symlinked to clang how do I change these symlinks